# Wpf bind multitrigger condition null value

Tags: wpf, binding, styles, dependency-properties, multitrigger

What I have is a custom window.  Added a bool dependencyproperty.  I want to use this dependency property as a condition for my triggers.  A way to get around my triggers so to speak.  Unfortunately I have propery non-null value exception being thrown.  Banging my head with this one.  I also tested the dependency property before the binding on the triggers.  It never hits the dependency property wrapper.  No errors thrown/shown when I do that.

DependencyProperty setup:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The override visibility property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverrideVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "OverrideVisibility", typeof(bool), typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the override visibility.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The override visibility.</value>
    public bool OverrideVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(OverrideVisibilityProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(OverrideVisibilityProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Trigger setup in style

```
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=OverrideVisibility}" Value="false" />  
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="WindowCloseButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Form xaml Setup:

```
<local:MyWindow x:Class="MyForm"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    Width="500"
                    Height="500"
                    OverrideVisibility="True">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not say exactly. Maybe here set type of `local:MyWindow`: `<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyWindow}}, Path=OverrideVisibility}" Value="false" />`.

Comment: Unfortunately the way I have it structured.  The Style with the trigger is in a resource dictionary in another namespace where I can't include the namespace for the custom window which is why I was using the find ancestor of type window.  It works on my other dependency properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is on this line:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=OverrideVisibility}" Value="false" />
```

Specifically, this is your error:

```
AncestorType={x:Type Window}
```

You probably have an error in your Output Window in Visual Studio that says something like:

```
Error: No OverrideVisibility property found on object Window
```

Instead of that `Binding`, use the name/type of your *custom* `Window`... something like this:

```
AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourCustomWindow}
```

Additionally, you said this:

> It never hits the dependency property wrapper

It wouldn't... they are just for *your* use... they're *not* used by the Framework. If you want to monitor what values are going through a `DependencyProperty`, then you need to register a `PropertyChangedCallback` event handler. You can find out more from the [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#checklist) page on MSDN.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ah, I just noticed the comments. You might still be able to do it if you can declare an Attached Property in an assembly that both your `Style` and your view have access to. If that's a possibility, then take a look at the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN to find out how to do that.

Finally, you can bind to an Attached Property like this:

```
<animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ownerType.propertyName)" .../>
```

This example was from the [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page on MSDN.